# Subroutes reverse order in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, frameworks, vue.js, vue-router

I wrote a small route with Vue.js router with a nested subroute, I expected (and it works) as an output:

- Load data from Main (1)
- Load data from Sub (2)

however when I hit the refresh button on the browser the order reverse itself to:

- Load data from Sub (2)
- Load data from Main (1)

```js
    var Main = Vue.extend({
      template:
        '<div class="foo">' +
          '<h2>This is Main!</h2>' +
          '<router-view></router-view>' +
        '</div>',
      ready: function() {
       console.log('Load data from Main (1)');
      }
    })
    
    var Sub = Vue.extend({
        template: '<p>This is sub!</p>',
        ready: function() {
        console.log('Load data from Sub (2)');
        }
    })
    
    // configure router
    var router = new VueRouter()
    
    router.map({
      '/': {
        component: Main,
        subRoutes: {
          '/bar': {
            component: Sub
          }
        }
      }
    })
    
    // start app
    var App = Vue.extend({})
    router.start(App, '#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/0.7.10/vue-router.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <a v-link="{ path: '/' }">Go main route</a>
    <a v-link="{ path: '/bar' }">Go to subroute</a>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

You can see a working copy at http://jsfiddle.net/L6tuweue/ just hit the reload button over the display section and keep your console open.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: U should use Promise for it. Because its async userLikes can be called first

Comment: Thanks for replying @GONG .. looking at the documentation, came out with more code but I am completely lost in a maze yet. Could you provide some example code? thanks!

Comment: One question, why you can't get both users and their likes in one query? I see no reason to separate it

Comment: Because the user might not have that 'section' enabled, that's also the reason why I inserted the router.go to likes within the main user detail route. I simplified the code before posting it (or tried to :-))

Comment: Don't know exactly, but try to do this on both methods: `this.$http.get("url" + this.$route.path, false)`. According to docs, vue-resource based on XMLHttpRequest and it have third parameter to turn off async. You can read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: Tried, didn't work.. thanks anyway! at least now thanks to you I have a starting point :-)

Comment: sorry, i don't have much time to explain it to you.

But here is version that should work, with some comments:

http://jsbin.com/humiqakuno/edit?html,output

Comment: Don't worry, tried your solution but could not make it work. I appreciate the effort and produced a JSFiddle to improve my question :-)